# Dynamics 365 sending api request for token python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, access-token, microsoft-dynamics

I have a successful connection set up in postman. I am trying to replicate the same in python but I am getting issues. I want to get the access token as I get from the Postman but in Python

**Postman environment variables:**
authurl = [https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource={{url}}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=%7B%7Burl%7D%7D)
[image]

**Authorization Setup :**

Type: OAuth 2.0
Add authorization data to: Request Headers

[image]

**Configuration New Token settings:**

[image]

I am using the following code in Python to replicate the same but I am getting the error "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)"

```
import requests
import json
 
#set these values to retrieve the oauth token
crmorg = 'https://xxx.crm6.dynamics.com' #base url for crm org
clientid = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' #application client id
username = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx' #username
userpassword = 'xxxxxxxx' #password

tokenendpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://xxx.crm6.dynamics.com'

     
#build the authorization token request
tokenpost = {
    'client_id':clientid,
    'resource':crmorg,
    'username':username,
    'password':userpassword,
    'grant_type':'password'
}
 
#make the token request
tokenres = requests.get(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)
tokenres.json()
```

Full error

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-ca0357600064> in <module>
     22 #make the token request
     23 tokenres = requests.get(tokenendpoint, data=tokenpost)
---> 24 tokenres.json()

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    908                     # used.
    909                     pass
--> 910         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    911 
    912     @property

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

c:\ProgramData\python36\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)
```

Comment: Could you please provide us the complete error details ?

Comment: @vickykumar I have added it in

Answer (score 0):

Ok, There are 2 main ways to achive Access Toke.

1. Clinet ID and Client Secret, you do not need user name and password. This is the recommended way and I would say go with this way.
2. Clinet Id but username and password.

you are using 2nd method.
your tokenendpint is as below

```
 tokenendpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://xxx.crm6.dynamics.com'
```

but rather you should have it

```
tokenendpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/ab758891-bfde-44ba-8f4d-49ed229d9156/oauth2/token' #oauth token endpoint
```

[Here is complete article for reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/friyanksblog/posts/integrate-microsoft-dynamics-365-ce-with-python-3-6)

Comment: I tried doing that but it didn't work. I get the same error

Comment: Then please go by 1st method anyhow it is recommended way

Comment: I don’t have a client secret for dynamics 365.

Comment: did yo managed to solve this?

Comment: Nope. I am still waiting for solution

Comment: I would recommend please go by client ID and secret.